# Model is not updating on blur event

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am quite new to Angular2 and I am trying to create a reactive form. E.g. I am trying to create an interactive date input.

My HTML:

```
<div class="date ui-input">
    <input type="text" name="dateD" [ngModel]="model.date | date:'dd'" (blur)="setDate($event.target.value, 'd')" maxlength="2" />
    <div>.</div>
    <input type="text" name="dateM" [ngModel]="model.date | date:'MM'" (blur)="setDate($event.target.value, 'm')" maxlength="2" />
    <div>.</div>
    <input type="text" name="dateY" [ngModel]="model.date | date:'y'" (blur)="setDate($event.target.value, 'y')" maxlength="4" />
</div>
```

And the corresponding TypeScript for setDate():

```
setDate(input:number, type:string[1]) {
    let min = 1;
    let max = 1;
    let fn = null;

    switch(type) {
        case 'd':
            max = 31;
            fn = 'setDate';
            break;
        case 'm':
            input -= 1;
            min = 0;
            max = 11;
            fn = 'setMonth';
            break;
        case 'y':
            min = 1990;
            max = 9999;
            fn = 'setFullYear';
            break;
    }
    if(input < min) {
        input = min;
    }
    else if(input > max) {
        input = max;
    }

    if(fn)
        this.model.date[fn](input);

    console.log(this.model.date);
}
```

The model is updating fine, I am checking that with `console.log()`. The view is not updating.

I was hoping that the input fields would show the correct date, as per `date`-pipe, but seems I am wrong. In Angular 1.x everything was much different, I understand, but yet I was able to achieve my goal.

Any suggestions? Is there maybe a function to "manually" update the model?

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to directly manipulate the value property of your form field. This doesn't trigger the update. Instead, use `patchValue` https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormControl-class.html

```
$event.target.patchValue({dateY: value});
```

For example I use it like this in my html:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
    <input formControlName="myValue" (ionChange)="recalculate($event)">
</form>
```

In my TS code:

```
public recalculate(e) {
    let currentValue = this.myForm.controls.get(myValue).value;
    this.myForm.patchValue({ myValue: currentValue / 10 });
}
```